# LyX: Горячие клавиши

Tags: lyx

В LyX для перехода в математический режим можно использовать сочетание клавиш <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>. Но, с другой стороны, там много еще других окружений, команд. А можно ли на эти объекты назначать сочетания клавиш?

Answer (score 1):

Я скопирую ответ со своего блога, чтоб по сто раз ответ не набирать. Итак. Вот, когда пишешь текст с теоремами, леммами, их доказательствами, перечислениями  и пр. в LyX, нужно переключать окружения с помощью вот этого переключателя:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

также для выполнения, например, какой-нибудь команды, расположенной на какой-нибудь, пусть даже активированной, доступной в основном окне программы, панели инструментов (для активации какой-либо панели инструментов нужно в **Вид>Панели инструментов**   поставить галочку напротив ставшей вам нужной панели инструментов) приходится использовать мышь. Когда ты пишешь что-то, что тебя очень занимает или что-то сложное, отвлечение на такое переключение мышью не всегда желательно. Лучше бы, если это все можно было делать клавой. И создатели LyX предусмотрели возможность решения этого вопроса каждым пользователем LyX самостоятельно. Рассмотрим, например, как определить сочетание клавиш для вставки окружения *Теорема*. Нажимаем на треугольничек с приведенного выше фото. В выпавшем списке щелкаем левой кнопкой мыши на пункте *Теорема*. При этом строка состояния, внизу окна, там, где обычно написано *Шрифт: По умолчанию*, на короткое время примет следующий вид:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И вот словосочетание *layout Theorem* нам-то и нужно. Далее идем в  **Инструменты> Настройки>Редактирование>Горячие клавиши**. Там нажимаем кнопку <kbd>Новый</kbd>. Появляется вот такое диалоговое окно:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В текстовое поле **Функции** вводим узнанное ранее словосочетание *layout Theorem*. Щелкаем левой кнопкой мышки в прямоугольник, расположенный справа от надписи **Горячая клавиша** и вводим придуманное нами сочетание клавиш для данной команды. Я, к примеру, т. к. большинство сочетаний клавиш, начинающихся с <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, уже занято, чтобы не заморачиваться с тем, какие сочетания клавиш с таким же началом существуют, какие - нет, начинаю свои сочетания клавиш с <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd> с цифрового блока, а дальше набор букв, индивидуальный для каждой команды. Этот индивидуальный набор я, чтобы не путаться, присваиваю, исходя из записи русского названия окружения, на которое я создаю сочетание клавиш, латинскими буквами (если я назначаю горячую клавишу на какую-нибудь команду, то придумываю для этой команды название из русских слов, а в горячей клавише использую латинские аналоги первых слов придуманного названия, см. ниже). Например, на окружение *Теорема* у меня назначено сочетание клавиш <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd>, на окружение *Доказательство* - сочетание <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd>+o (плюсы в прямоугольник, расположенный справа от надписи **Горячая клавиша** вводить не нужно, также как и не нужно их нажимать при использовании созданных таким образом сочетаний клавиш). Все, нажимаем кнопки <kbd>Сохранить</kbd> или <kbd>Применить</kbd>. Так же мы назначим сочетание клавиш на команду, к примеру, **Вставка>Примечание>Комментарий**. Щелкаем левой кнопкой мыши эту команду, строка состояния при этом принимает следующий вид: *(note-insert Comment)*. А вот, например, команда `font-itаl` делает шрифт наклонным. Поэтому у меня на эту команду поставлена горячая клавиша `Ctrl`+`S`+`H`+`N` (это я по поводу обещанного выше в ссылке *см. ниже*). Все остальные действия аналогичны действиям, описанным выше. Спасибо за внимание и... понимание.))