# Как к LyX подцепить Maxima?

Tags: windows-7, lyx

В LyX, когда курсор мигает в строчной или выклочной формуле в меню **Правка** появляется подменю **Метематика**. В этом подменю есть еще одно подменю **Использовать систему компьютерной алгебры**, в котором есть команда *maxima*. Что ж, выглядит это многообещающе, осталось только подключить саму программу Maxima к LyX. Не подскажите, как это сделать?

Answer (score 1):

А делается енто дело вот как. Я об этом прочитал [здесь](https://cyberleninka.ru/article/n/lyx-i-sistemy-simvolnoy-matematiki), однако, ввиду возможности устаревания ссылки, перескажу еще здесь. Итак, делается это следующим образом. Ищем папку, в которую установлена Maxima. У этой программы есть 2 файла, запускающих эту программу в разных видах - wxmaxima.exe и xmaxima.exe. Мне нужен путь к папке, в которой находится файл xmaxima.exe. Я предполагаю, что при установке Maxima папка, в которую предлагалось извлечь ну, или записать файлы Maxima (не знаю, как это называется), не была изменена пользователем. Тогда эта папка (во всяком случае, для версии Maxima 5.27.0) - `C:\Program Files\Maxima-5.27.0\bin`. Копируем этот путь. Открываем LyX, идем **Инструменты>Настройки...>Пути**, щелкаем левой кнопкой мышки в текстовое поле ***Пути***, уходим в окончание этого поля и без пробела с последней буквой этого поля вставляем `;` и ранее скопированный путь `C:\Program Files\Maxima-5.27.0\bin</pu>`, нажимаем *Сохранить*, все, LyX готов для использования в нем Maxima. Входим в математический или в выклочный (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>) режим, вводим в нем для проверки функционирования простейшую команду программы Maxima:

```
ratsimp(a+a)
```

Идем **Правка>Математика>Использовать систему компьютерной алгебры** и нажимаем **Maxima**. В результате справа от моей команды, в математическом или в выклочном этом же режиме (этом же прямоугольнике) появляется вот что:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Знак `=` появляется не от ввода пользователем, а автоматически, после вызова Maxima. Чтобы для каждого вызова Maxima не нажимать много раз мышку, я [создал горячую клавишу](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/978064/lyx-%d0%93%d0%be%d1%80%d1%8f%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%88%d0%b8/978065#978065) на словосочетание *math-extern maxima*. А чтобы после окончания работы Maxima  в математическом (выклочном) режиме исчезали команды Maxima, нужно перед ее вызовом, находясь в математическом (выклочном) режиме выделить эти команды, как выделяют перед копированием.