# Как в программе LyX использовать буфер команды?

Tags: lyx

Если мы пройдем **Вид>Панели инструментов**, то там среди прочих панелей мы увидим панель *Буфер команды*. Что это такое?

Comment: Вопрос взят из matematikaandinformatika.blogspot.com/p/lyx_3.html. В нем и есть ответ.

Comment: Я знаю: это мой блог. Здесь же я создаю еще один источник информации по этому вопросу.

Answer (score 0):

Рассказываю. Во-первых, этой функцией мы можем выполнить какую-либо команду по словосочетанию для этой команды, на которое мы назначали горячую клавишу для этой команды [вот в этом посте](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/978064/lyx-%D0%93%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%88%D0%B8/978065#978065). Именно, открываем эту панель (для открытия этой панели мы на словосочетание *toolbar-toggle* minibuffer назначаем сочетание клавиш `Ctrl`+`0`+`B`+`K`, тогда закрыть эту панель можно тем же сочетанием клавиш, а чтобы перебросить курсор в буфер команды, используется сочетание клавиш `Alt`+`X`, назначенное на словосочетание *command-execute*. Ну, это сочетание клавиш  имеется в LyX изначально, нам его назначать не нужно). Итак, вот мы открыли эту панель. Если мы туда введем, к примеру,

[image]

(там после слова *Theorem* при этом все еще мигает курсор, просто сфотографировать так не получилось) и нажмем клавишу `Enter`, то, как я понял, в том абзаце, в котором мигал (или мигает сейчас, зависит от способа перевода курсора в буфер команды, см. примечание ниже), до переброса в буфер команды курсора, курсор, в основном окне прогры LyX  начнется окружение *Теорема*.

Примечание.  Если мы курсор переводили в буфер команды сочетанием клавиш, то в основном окне LyX курсор тоже остается на прежнем месте, а в буфере команды появляется еще один курсор и, таким образом, в окне LyX появляется 2 курсора, но, к сожалению, как я ни старался, сфотографировать 2 курсора не удалось, курсор в буфере команды вновь категорически отказывается фотографироваться). Если же мы курсор туда помещаем нажатием левой кнопки мышки, курсор получается только в буфере команды. Однако в обоих случаях после нажатия `Enter` положение курсора становится таким, каким оно было до перевода курсора в Буфер команды.

Для ввода формулы текстовой (выклочной) формулы через буфер команды, эта формула должна начинаться с math-mode (math-display). Если мы в буфере команды напишем

[image]

(наконец-то удалось схватить 2 курсора!) и нажмем `Enter`, то в основном окне LyX между "в" и "такой" появится греческая (у греческом зале, у греческом зале...) буква пи под знаком корня и все это будет выглядеть точно так же, как если бы мы вводили эту формулу из основного окна LyX без применения буфера команды, через (в данном случае) `Ctrl`+`M` и т. д., и т. п. Само собой разумеется, буфер команды для ввода таких простых формул представляет мало интереса, однако... Ввод таких формул, как

```
\begin{tabular}{|c|cc|c|}
\hline А & Б & В & Г\\\hhline{|=|~~|-|}
Д & Е & Ж & З \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
```

текстовой или выклочной формуле - дело нереальное из-за неправильной интерпретации символа `\`. Не забываем подключать пакет *hhline* (отмечу, что этот пакет оказался для меня не совсем обычным: когда я его подключил в своем документе, сначала в TeXworks, чтоб посмотреть, вообще работают или нет подобные коды, по сообщениям в *Выводе работы программы* у меня создалось такое впечатление, что его нет среди установленных пакетов, я в Менеджер пакетов - нет такого пакета, я в репозиторий - нет, ну, думаю, может, как большинство пакетов - в `C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex` - нет. И только поиском по компьютеру я нашел его в `C:\Program Files\MiKTeX
2.9\tex\latex\tools`). И один из способов решения этой проблемы - ввод таких формул через буфер команды:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После нажатия `Enter` получаем ожидаемый результат:

[image]

Однако, такой способ срабатывает не всегда. Например, при попытке вставки через буфер таблицы

```
math-mode \begin{tabular}{lr@{--}@{\qquad 
Obed\quad}r@{--}cc} \text{Понедельник}  &  
8^{30}
&  15  &  11  &  12 \\  Вторник   &  12  & 
19  & 15  &  16 \\ \end{tabular}
```

после нажатия `Enter` в понимании компьютера слово *Obed* (я специально написал его латинскими буквами) сливается с командой *\qquad* и возникает ошибка при экспорте (получении pdf, в чем вы там экспортируете - в  pdflatex или еще в чем). Выход из этой ситуации - вставка кодов таких формул, окружений в код TeX (*Ctrl*+*l*) или в *Вставка>preview* (туда опять-таки нужно вставлять код TeX). Все эти заковыристые формулы с @ и прочей прелестью взяты мной из книги Львовского "Набор и верстка..." Ну, вы знаете.