# Для чего нужен файл default.def в программе LyX?

Tags: lyx

В `C:\Program Files\LyX 2.0\Resources\commands` есть файл *default.def*. Для чего нужен этот файл?

Answer (score 0):

Отвечаю. Я в августе 19-го обнаружил, что изменения, внесенные мной 12.06.19 в этот файл, только тогда вступили в силу. В июне же эти изменения этого файла никак не проявлялись. Видимо, в течение этого промежутка времени я сделал что-то, связанное с программой LyX, но что именно, сказать не могу. Зато сразу вступали тогда и вступают сейчас в силу изменения в файле с тем же названием, но только расположенном в другой папке - в папке `C:\Users\ДИОНИС\AppData\Roaming\LyX2.0\commands`. Итак, этот файл нужен для того, чтобы в этом файле присваивать имена комбинациям команд, которые (команды) мы обычно используем в [буфере команд](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1066002/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B5-lyx-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%84%D0%B5%D1%80-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%8B) с тем, чтобы затем вызывать любую из этих комбинаций команд опять же через буфер команд с помощью имени, присвоенного этой комбинации. Вот примеры для определения таких имен таких комбинаций в этом файле:

```
\define "corpi" "command-sequence math-mode; math-insert {\displaystyle \intop_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-x^{2}}dx=\dfrac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}}; char-right; char-right;"
\define "vstgr" "command-sequence vc-command U \"$$p\" \"vstavka-grafiki.bat\""
```

Вызов так определенной команды, например, *vstgr*, осуществляется в буфере команды следующим образом:

```
call vstgr
```

Я с помощью этой команды вставляю графику в окне программы LyX, не отрывая рук от клавы. При этом в дело вступает файл *vstavka-grafiki.bat*. Что внутри этого файла и как он работает, я расскажу в другой теме на этом форуме: к тому, о чем я рассказываю здесь, это не имеет почти никакого отношения. Здесь же отмечу еще только, что, как я понял, команда

```
command-sequence
```

употребляется здесь тогда, когда в определяемой комбинации команд имеется несколько команд для соединения этих команд в одно целое, а вообще эту команду можно употреблять с той же целью непосредственно для ввода руками в буфер команды, когда из него нужно выполнить несколько команд за один ввод и когда [задается горячая клавиша](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/978064/lyx-%D0%93%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%88%D0%B8) на последовательность из нескольких команд.

Comment: Интересно, а что плохого в том, что я предоставил на русском языке инфу, которую (на русском языке) днем с огнем не найдешь?